# Optimize NetSuite restlet to avoid timeout error

Tags: netsuite, suitescript, restlet

I'm writing a restlet that will return all Bill, Credit Card, and Journal transactions within a NetSuite account (see code below). My issue is that given the volume of data (100k+ transaction records), I'm getting a timeout error. Is there any way for me to optimize my code to avoid this timeout error? Is there a way for me to pass the restlet parameters around the PageRanges and just make multiple calls?

```
/**
 *@NApiVersion 2.x
 *@NScriptType Restlet
 */
 define(['N/error', 'N/search'],
 function(error, search) {
     function doValidation(args, argNames, methodName) {
         for (var i = 0; i < args.length; i++)
             if (!args[i] && args[i] !== 0)
                 throw error.create({
                     name: 'MISSING_REQ_ARG',
                     message: 'Missing a required argument: [' + argNames[i] + '] for method: ' + methodName
                 });
     }
     function _get(context) {
         doValidation('GET');
        
         var mySearch = search.create({
            type: search.Type.TRANSACTION,
            columns: ['account', 'recordtype','trandate', 'tranid', 'memo', 'amount', 'department', 'entity' ],
            filters: [['recordtype', 'is', 'vendorbill'], 'or', ['recordtype', 'is', 'creditcardcharge'],'or', ['recordtype', 'is', 'journalentry']]
        });
        results = []
        var myPagedData = mySearch.runPaged({
            pageSize: 1000
        })

        myPagedData.pageRanges.forEach(function(pageRange){
            var myPage = myPagedData.fetch({index: pageRange.index})
            results.push(myPage.data)
        })
        return results
         }  
         
     return {
         get: _get,
     };
 });
```

Comment: Instead of your `forEach` only fetch the data from a single page. You get some metadata about the pagedData (e.x. whether is the last page or not). So you can call the restlet multiple times in a paginated way.

Comment: @W.S. Looking at the pagedData metadata to retrieve the index of each page makes sense to me, but I'm confused at how to pass that index data in each request to the restlet. How would I modify the restlet URL to pass that data?

Comment: You can pass the index as an extra URL parameter (ex. /app/site/hosting/restlet.nl?script=100&deploy=1&page=1). The `context` will represent the URL parameters as an object (ex. to get the index/page, just use context.page). If no index/page is specified in the request, just return the (meta)data from the first page.

Answer (score 0):

You can refresh the restLet for time exceed error as it has 5 minute(300 seconds) time limit only.
you can use **N/runtime** moduleto get its governance limit and **N/cache** module to store the already done data.
check the remaining governance and curren t time in loop.
and break the loop and call again restLet after storing already done data using cache module. Pass remaining data as a parameter while calling.

```
 var script_startdate = new Date(); // this will be in starting on script 
function
script_Start_time = script_startdate.getTime(); 
for(var i=0;i<i+2;i++){   // here i used infinity loop, you can use yours
var script_workdate = new Date();
var script_workTime = script_workdate.getTime();
remainingTime= script_workTime - script_Start_time;
var remainingContentIndex=content.indexOf(content[i]);
var remainingUsage = runtime.getCurrentScript().getRemainingUsage();
if ((remainingTime> 240000) ||(remainingUsage<80))break;
}

if ((substraction > 240000) ||(remainingUsage<80))
   {
      var myCacheRecId = cache.getCache({
           name: 'temporaryCacheRecId',
           scope: cache.Scope.PUBLIC
           });
        myCacheRecId.put({
              key: 'myvar',
              value: "already completed data""
              });
     var slice_index=remainingContentIndex+1;
     var remainingContent=content.slice(slice_index);
     var content=content.toString(remainingContent);
              redirect.redirect({
                scriptId: 'customscript_scriptid,
                deploymentId: 'customdeploy_deployid',
                  parameters: {
                       content: content
                        }
                      });
                  log.debug("called restlet", "called restlet");
    
           };
```